# How much time does the HOG descriptor training take?

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, object-detection, matlab-cvst

We have a project that will identify a logo from an image. We initially used a Haar classifier, but training a Haar classifier take lots of time (4 days per logo on our Core i5 machine). 
To train it for 300+ logos will take a lot of time (we do not have any high performance computers).
So, we have decided to move to a HOG based object detector, hoping that its training will take significantly less time.

Does anyone have an idea how much time HOG descriptor training takes? We would be training on the about 100 positive and 100 negative 600x800 pixel images per logo (on a machine with a Core i5 processor).

Answer (score 3):

Unanswerable, depends on the number of bins and other implementation details. Probably also on the content of the images. Don't expect it to be super fast with 60k images though. If I were you I would seriously consider downscaling the images, 600x800 is much larger than what you need for recognition. 150x200 should still be recognizable, but all the computations would be 16x faster.

Comment: if we would have down scale our image say to your figure (or even less with logos no issue) what time will it take in training, please tell according to your general idea., 
or what time it had taken when you have trained HOG descriptor in your project/task..

Comment: @user1441867: For a pedestrian recognition project a while ago, it would take about 2 minutes to calculate the HOG descriptors for 3000 images with a resolution of 60x120. Not sure if this is a reliable and scalable indication, but it would scale to 2*(60,000/3000)*((150*200)/(120*60)) = 166 minutes of training in total for your problem.

Comment: Thank you..,
Would you can also give an link to some tutorial/tool that can be used train HOG descriptor.. i have explored but found very little about it..
It will be very helpful if u provide( link of) tool that can generate the hog descriptor(trained for specific object).

Comment: @user1441867: You don't *train* a HOG descriptor, you calculate it, as it's just a different representation of the original data that is independent of the classifier. You could use a classifier like SVM on the HOG descriptors. Take a look at the [PRTools](http://www.prtools.org/) toolbox if you don't want to make your own classifier.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitly downscale your inputs images. For example, HOG descriptor is usually extract from 64x128 pedestrian images, to train an accurate pedestrian detector.
Training Haar classifier is always time consuming and it's hard to predict how much time it will take since it can block on specific stage.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give you any specific numbers, but training with HOG is orders of magnitude faster than training with Haar-like features.  HOG also uses much less memory. Additionally, you have the option to use the LBP features, in both OpenCV and the `trainCascadeObjectDetector` function in MATLAB.  Using LBP, is also much faster than using Haar.